# What is erlang emsgsize?

Tags: erlang, bittorrent, gen-tcp

Our school project is a BitTorrent client. Today i suddenly got a `{tcp_error,#Port<0.2095>,emsgsize}` error and my question is what caused this error? I have `option {packet,4}` on `gen_tcp` so my guess is that the length off the package does not match the 4 first bytes? That would be really strange because all BitTorrent messages except for the handshake have first 4 bytes len. Yesterday we were able to download and now i get these messages. Note that some messages arrives just fine. Thanks for your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Maybe you try to send/receive message that have size more than 2GB?

Answer (score 2):

you will get an emsgsize error when the packet is bigger than your receive buffer (recbuf option) or when the packet is bigger than the specified maximum packet size (packet_size options).

Answer (score -1):

Probably one of the packets is not sent with the correct header, which Erlang is interpreting as a header that claims the packet is very large.